# Joint probability distribution of AB given A=X/Y, B=Y, the distributions of X and Y

Tags: probability-distributions

I have recently been brushing up on some statistics in preparation for further study and I have encountered this question that has stumped me quite a bit:

Find the joint probability distribution of A and B given that:

$A = \frac{X}{Y^2}$  , 
$B = Y$

$f_X(x)=2-2x$ for $0<x<y$

$f_Y(y)=4y^3$ for $0<y<1$

$0$ otherwise in both cases.

I understand that B will have the same distribution as Y, but when it comes to finding the joint probability distribution of A and B, I'm not convinced that merely substituting $Y=B$ and multiplying both sides of the equation for A to get $AB=X$ is valid. Am I right in this assumption? If so, how do I find the distribution of A and B?

Thank you for your time in helping me with this!

Comment: $AB$ does not have a _joint_ distribution: $(A,B)$ does.  The distribution of $AB$ or of $(A,B)$ cannot be computed from the information that you are writing down. What, for example, is $y$ in $f(x)=2$ for $0 < x < y$ where the right side depends on $y$ but the left side does not?

Comment: I apologize for the slip-up. I was in a bit of a rush to get out of the house last night and I made a big mistake for the equation of $f(x)$. It's now corrected as above. As for the dependence on y, in my mind I thought it was something to the effect of $0<x<y<1$ since y is positive and between 0 and 1. If I'm not mistaken in this, x can take values between 0 and 1 as long as it's less than y (i.e: left of y=x).

Comment: What name, if any, do you ascribe to your $f(\cdot)$? It is a commonly-accepted convention that a symbol in an equation or in mathematical discourse should mean the same thing wherever it occurs. So, what is the value of $f(\frac 12)$? One equation ($f(y)=4y^3$ when $0<y<1$) gives it as $\frac 12$ whereas the other simply says $2-2\times\frac 12 = 1$ if $0 < \frac 12 < y$ and $0$ otherwise. As to what $y$ is, we have no way of telling.

Comment: My apologies for putting the equations poorly. This is my first question on this site and I had a bit of confusion with the formatting. I meant the function above as two separate functions; one for random variable X and one for random variable Y (i.e: $f_X(x)$ and $f_Y(y)$) I

Comment: Oh, dear, this process seem unlikely to converge any time soon.  1. _No one_ can find the joint distribution of $A=X/Y$ and $B=Y$ from the (marginal) densities $f_X$ and $f_Y$ alone: the _joint_ density of $X$ and $Y$ is needed.  Sometimes the joint density is provided by adding the statement "$X$ and $Y$ are _independent_ random variables" to the specification of the marginal densities. In such cases, we have that $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=f_X(x)f_Y(y)$ for all $x$ and $y$. 2. Your $f_X(x)$ is nonsensical since the right side depends on $y$ and the left does not.  3. $f_X(x)$ does not integrate to $1$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Use the [method of transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Absolutely_continuous_univariate_distributions) using Jacobians.

Comment: Thanks for that link! I have seen some explanation regarding division of random variables (i.e: the quotient distribution section), but I'm unclear if a similar approach can be taken with $A = \frac{X}{Y^2}$